# UnExpected Method Call Assertion Error

Tags: easymock

I am new to EasyMock and am struggling with the following issue that i am facing while running the test cases. The unit test is failing as "UnExpected Method Call execute" .Firstly Here is my application code:

```
class Filter {

Filter(FilterExecutor f) {
   filter = f;
}
static FilterExecutor filter;

void handle() {

   filter.execute(object);
}
//some logic here
};

class FilterExtension extends Filter {

FilterExtension(FilterExecutor f) {
   super(f);
}
void handle() {
   //some logic here
   super.handle();
}
}
```

Test cases :

```
class Tests {

FilterExecutor f;
@Override
public void Tests() {
  f=EasyMock.createMock(FilterExecutor.class);
}
@Test
public void test1 {

  EasyMock.expect(f.execute(object)).andReturn(Obj1);
  EasyMock.replay(f);
  FilterExtension test = new FilterExtension(f);
  test.handle();
  //Assert
}

@Test
public void test2 {

  //More or less similar to above
  EasyMock.expect(f.execute(object)).andReturn(Obj1);
  EasyMock.replay(f);
  FilterExtension test = new FilterExtension(f);
  test.handle();
}
}
```

If the above test cases are run individually then the tests are passing succssfully. If they are ran together then one of the test passes and other gives an assertion error ""UnExpected Method Call execute". And also if i add at the end of one test case "Filter.filter=null" then both the test cases are succeeding. Can somebody please explain me why this behavior is observed?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems I'm seeing here:

1. The dependency is declared as static, but is then initialised in the constructors from a parameter.
2. The object being passed to the `execute(object)` method is not being passed to the `handle()` method.

Problem 1 is a design issue ore than anything else. If you want to initialise the `FilterExecutor` each time you create a new `Filter` (or `FilterExetnsion`) then why not make it an instance variable? It's obviously inherently linked to a specific instance of the class, not the class itself.

Problem 2 is potentially a design issue, or could be about expectations within your tests. Within the method call `test.handle()` a call to `filter.execute(object)` is made. However, the object that is passed to `execute` is not provided by your test class. This means the object passed in `filter.execute(object)` is not the same object as you've told it to expect in `EasyMock.expect(f.execute(object)).andReturn(Obj1);`

There are two ways to solve this:

- A) Change your expectation to use a Capture.
- B) Change your `handle` method to take in the object, then provide that to the `handle` method call in you test.

For option A, [See this good Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826173/how-to-test-with-easymock-capture)

I think the test methods would look a bit like this:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    final Capture<Object> object = new Capture<Object>();
    EasyMock.expect(this.mockFilterExecutor.execute(EasyMock.capture(object))).andReturn(new Object());
    EasyMock.replay(this.mockFilterExecutor);
    final FilterExtension test = new FilterExtension(this.mockFilterExecutor);
    test.handle();

    final Object capturedObject = object.getValue();
    //Assert
}
```

For option B You could do something like the following, but obviously, this won't be viable if the object you provide to `execute()` can't be constructed or received from outside of the `handle()` method

Your handle method in the `Filter` class would look like this:

```
public void handle(final Object object) {
    this.filter.execute(object);
}
```

Your handle method in the `FilterExtension` class would look like this:

```
@Override
public void handle(final Object object) {
    super.handle(object);
}
```

And your test would look like this:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    final Object object = new Object();
    EasyMock.expect(this.mockFilterExecutor.execute(object)).andReturn(object);
    EasyMock.replay(this.mockFilterExecutor);
    final FilterExtension test = new FilterExtension(this.mockFilterExecutor);
    test.handle(object);
    //Assert
}
```